# How to get the profile picture from facebook, gmail, twitter by using DotNetOpenAuthentication?(Description Indside)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I'm using DotNetOpenAuth along with Microsoft.AspNet.Membership. I've done upto user login and save his mail id into my database with the help of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx). Now I need to get the profile picture of a user from whatever service(facebook,gmail, etc.,) the user used.

I googled yet not found how to achieve this. If somebody know this means, please share it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The process of doing this won't be the same for every service.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know for Facebook, once you have the users link, you can use that to get their picture via Graph: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/

I basically use this:

```
graph.Link.AbsoluteUri.Replace("www.facebook", "graph.facebook") + "/picture"
```

Have not messed with Google or Twitter yet...